# OneNote 2010 creates empty backup folder

Tags: ms-office, onenote

I am using OnenOte 2010. When I try to backup all my notes after specifying the backup folder location, the backup process finish successfully but the backup folder is empty. Where does onenote save the backups to? And how do we restore from onenote backup?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer the restore: After backup occurs you should see a set of folders. Among them, a subdirectory backup. In this are your complete set of folders that represent your notebooks and the notes inside. Copy where you will, close the old and open these.

Comment: That is my issue. I have a backup folder after the backup process completes but it's empty.

Comment: Try changing to a different location? Are you pointing to a share drive or to the local hard drive where onenote is?

Comment: Oh. Yes its pointing to where the OneNote is. I will try another directory. thanks